# How to "sudo" with Powershell (elevate Powershell, running a command as admin) on Linux?

Tags: linux, powershell, admin, powershell-core, powershell-7.0

If you want to run a command as admin on PowerShell on Windows, you can write something like this:

```
Start-Process foo -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '...'
```

But it is not possible on Linux. Powershell will return you the following error: `Start-Process: The parameter '-Verb' is not supported for the cmdlet 'Start-Process' on this edition of PowerShell.` Indeed, According to the [Powershell online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-7), "*the* [-Verb] *parameter does not apply for non-Windows systems*", so it is not possible to run Powershell as admin like this on Linux.

My question is simple: **how to elevate Powershell privileges on Linux?** How can I simulate BASH's `sudo ...` with Powershell on Linux? I know that you can make a workaround with bash and some thing like `sudo pwsh -Command '...'`, but I am looking for a "100% PowerShell" way to do this.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

PS: By "PowerShell", I mean "PowerShell 7", the latest one.

Comment: Why do you need a "100% PowerShell" way?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I am a Powershell user on Linux and I would like to know how to do. PowerShell is a bright CLI and I would like to get rid of Bash on my computer as much as possible.

Comment: Isn't sudo just a standard executable on Linux (i.e., nothing specifically to do with bash)? Why not just use it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `powershell-ish` way of doing this, because `elevation` feature depends on OS. In both Windows and Linux you actually start a new process under a different security context (and under separate user session), but in Windows there is built-in elevation mechanism using `verbs`. Linux does not support verbs, and you have to use `sudo` or `su`.

If you go little bit deeper, `Start-Process -Verb` under Windows creates appropriate `[System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo]` with `.Verb` filled and runs process using `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($ProcessStartInfo)`.

So, under Linux you internally have the same except instead of setting `.Verb`, you set `FileName` to `sudo` and move old value to arguments.

Like there is no any *universal* method to drive both bicycle and spaceship.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo pwsh -c`:

```
PS> (sudo pwsh { gci -r /opt/tomcat/*.sh | ? name -like 'startup*' }).fullname
/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Or from bash

```
$ echo "Secret content" | sudo tee /root/secretfile.txt > /dev/null
$ sudo chmod 600 /root/secretfile.txt
$ sudo pwsh -Command "Get-Content /root/secretfile.txt"
```

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on this proposed solution?

Comment: @greaterKing I updated my answer with another example.